# UISLIDER problemas con frames

Tags: swift, xcode

Tengo un UISLIDER

que se ve de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando esta cerquita de terminar de cargar se completa el pintado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pude fixear arreglar esto haciendo que el UISlider sea mas bajo de altura pero me gustaria tener este efecto sin importar la altura

Mi codigo :

```
class CustomUISlider  : UISlider {
     @IBInspectable open var trackWidth:CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet {setNeedsDisplay()}
    }

    override open func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let defaultBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return CGRect(
            x: defaultBounds.origin.x,
            y: defaultBounds.origin.y + defaultBounds.size.height/2 - trackWidth/2,
            width: defaultBounds.size.width,
            height: trackWidth
        )
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    
        self.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 25
    }
 }
```

ViewController

```
self.sliderEnviar.setValue(0, animated: true)
    self.sliderEnviar.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    self.sliderEnviar.backgroundColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_MAGENTA_CLARO
    self.sliderEnviar.minimumTrackTintColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_VERDE_BOTON
    
    self.sliderEnviar.maximumTrackTintColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_MAGENTA_CLARO
    self.sliderEnviar.setThumbImage(UIImage.init(named: "slider"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

Tengo adaptado esta clase que te puede servir. No hereda de `UISlider` sino de `UIControl`.

```
class CustomUISlider: UIControl {
    
    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        setup()
    }
```

En el slider agregas la clase `CustomUISlider` y luego agregas el siguiente código; recalco que es una simplificación del código original.

```
public required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        setup()
    }
    
    public convenience init(frame: CGRect = .zero, completion: ((CustomUISlider) -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        completion?(self)
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var minValue: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            refresh()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var maxValue: CGFloat = 100.0 {
        didSet {
            refresh()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var selectedMinValue: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            if selectedMinValue < minValue {
                selectedMinValue = minValue
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable open var selectedMaxValue: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            if selectedMaxValue > maxValue {
                selectedMaxValue = maxValue
            }
        }
    }
    
    open var minLabelFont: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0) {
        didSet {
            minLabel.font = minLabelFont as CFTypeRef
            minLabel.fontSize = minLabelFont.pointSize
        }
    }
    
    open var maxLabelFont: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0) {
        didSet {
            maxLabel.font = maxLabelFont as CFTypeRef
            maxLabel.fontSize = maxLabelFont.pointSize
        }
    }
    
    open var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        return formatter
    }()
    
    @IBInspectable open var hideLabels: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            minLabel.isHidden = hideLabels
            maxLabel.isHidden = hideLabels
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var labelsFixed: Bool = false
    
    @IBInspectable open var minDistance: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            if minDistance < 0.0 {
                minDistance = 0.0
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var maxDistance: CGFloat = .greatestFiniteMagnitude {
        didSet {
            if maxDistance < 0.0 {
                maxDistance = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var minLabelColor: UIColor?
    @IBInspectable open var maxLabelColor: UIColor?
    @IBInspectable open var handleColor: UIColor?
    @IBInspectable open var handleBorderColor: UIColor?
    @IBInspectable open var colorBetweenHandles: UIColor?
    @IBInspectable open var initialColor: UIColor?
    
    @IBInspectable open var disableRange: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            minLabel.isHidden = disableRange
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var enableStep: Bool = false
    @IBInspectable open var step: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    @IBInspectable open var handleImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            guard let image = handleImage else {
                return
            }
            
            var handleFrame = CGRect.zero
            handleFrame.size = image.size
            
            rightHandle.frame = handleFrame
            rightHandle.contents = image.cgImage
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var handleDiameter: CGFloat = 16.0 {
        didSet {
            rightHandle.cornerRadius = handleDiameter / 2.0
            rightHandle.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: handleDiameter, height: handleDiameter)
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var selectedHandleDiameterMultiplier: CGFloat = 1.7
    @IBInspectable open var lineHeight: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            updateLineHeight()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var handleBorderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            rightHandle.borderWidth = handleBorderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable open var labelPadding: CGFloat = 8.0
    @IBInspectable open var minLabelAccessibilityLabel: String?
    @IBInspectable open var maxLabelAccessibilityLabel: String?
    @IBInspectable open var minLabelAccessibilityHint: String?
    @IBInspectable open var maxLabelAccessibilityHint: String?
    
    private enum HandleTracking { case none, left, right }
    private var handleTracking: HandleTracking = .none
    private let sliderLine: CALayer = CALayer()
    private let sliderLineBetweenHandles: CALayer = CALayer()
    private let leftHandle: CALayer = CALayer()
    private let rightHandle: CALayer = CALayer()
    
    fileprivate let minLabel: CATextLayer = CATextLayer()
    fileprivate let maxLabel: CATextLayer = CATextLayer()
    
    private var minLabelTextSize: CGSize = .zero
    private var maxLabelTextSize: CGSize = .zero
    private var previousStepMinValue: CGFloat?
    private var previousStepMaxValue: CGFloat?
    
    private var accessibleElements: [UIAccessibilityElement] = []
    private var leftHandleAccessibilityElement: UIAccessibilityElement {
        let element: CustomUISliderLeftElement = CustomUISliderLeftElement(accessibilityContainer: self)
        element.isAccessibilityElement = true
        element.accessibilityLabel = minLabelAccessibilityLabel
        element.accessibilityHint = minLabelAccessibilityHint
        element.accessibilityValue = minLabel.string as? String
        element.accessibilityFrame = convert(leftHandle.frame, to: nil)
        element.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraits.adjustable
        return element
    }
    
    private var rightHandleAccessibilityElement: UIAccessibilityElement {
        let element: CustomUISliderRightElement = CustomUISliderRightElement(accessibilityContainer: self)
        element.isAccessibilityElement = true
        element.accessibilityLabel = maxLabelAccessibilityLabel
        element.accessibilityHint = maxLabelAccessibilityHint
        element.accessibilityValue = maxLabel.string as? String
        element.accessibilityFrame = convert(rightHandle.frame, to: nil)
        element.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraits.adjustable
        return element
    }
    
    open override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        if handleTracking == .none {
            updateLineHeight()
            updateColors()
        }
    }
    
    open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: 65.0)
    }
    
    open override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let touchLocation: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        let insetExpansion: CGFloat = -30.0
        let isTouchingRightHandle: Bool = rightHandle.frame.insetBy(dx: insetExpansion, dy: insetExpansion).contains(touchLocation)
        
        guard isTouchingRightHandle else { return false }
        
        let distanceFromLeftHandle: CGFloat = touchLocation.distance(to: leftHandle.frame.center)
        let distanceFromRightHandle: CGFloat = touchLocation.distance(to: rightHandle.frame.center)
        
        if distanceFromLeftHandle < distanceFromRightHandle && !disableRange {
            handleTracking = .left
        } else if selectedMaxValue == maxValue && leftHandle.frame.midX == rightHandle.frame.midX {
            handleTracking = .left
        } else {
            handleTracking = .right
        }
        
        let handle: CALayer = (handleTracking == .left) ? leftHandle : rightHandle
        animate(handle: handle, selected: true)
        
        return true
    }
    
    open override func continueTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        guard handleTracking != .none else { return false }
        
        let location: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        let percentage: CGFloat = (location.x - sliderLine.frame.minX - handleDiameter / 2.0) / (sliderLine.frame.maxX - sliderLine.frame.minX)
        let selectedValue: CGFloat = percentage * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue
        
        switch handleTracking {
            case .left:
                selectedMinValue = min(selectedValue, selectedMaxValue)
            case .right:
                if disableRange && selectedValue >= minValue {
                    selectedMaxValue = selectedValue
                } else {
                    selectedMaxValue = max(selectedValue, selectedMinValue)
            }
            case .none:
                break
        }
        
        refresh()
        
        return true
    }
    
    open override func endTracking(_ touch: UITouch?, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let handle: CALayer = (handleTracking == .left) ? leftHandle : rightHandle
        animate(handle: handle, selected: false)
        handleTracking = .none
    }
    
    open override func accessibilityElementCount() -> Int {
        return accessibleElements.count
    }
    
    open override func accessibilityElement(at index: Int) -> Any? {
        return accessibleElements[index]
    }
    
    open override func index(ofAccessibilityElement element: Any) -> Int {
        guard let element = element as? UIAccessibilityElement else { return 0 }
        return accessibleElements.firstIndex(of: element) ?? 0
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        isAccessibilityElement = false
        accessibleElements = [rightHandleAccessibilityElement]
        
        layer.addSublayer(sliderLine)
        layer.addSublayer(sliderLineBetweenHandles)
        
        rightHandle.cornerRadius = handleDiameter / 2.0
        rightHandle.borderWidth = handleBorderWidth
        layer.addSublayer(rightHandle)
        
        let handleFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: handleDiameter, height: handleDiameter)
        rightHandle.frame = handleFrame
        
        refresh()
    }
    
    private func percentageAlongLine(for value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        guard minValue < maxValue else { return 0.0 }
        
        let maxMinDif: CGFloat = maxValue - minValue
        let valueSubtracted: CGFloat = value - minValue
        
        return valueSubtracted / maxMinDif
    }
    
    private func xPositionAlongLine(for value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let percentage: CGFloat = percentageAlongLine(for: value)
        let maxMinDif: CGFloat = sliderLine.frame.maxX - sliderLine.frame.minX
        let offset: CGFloat = percentage * maxMinDif
        
        return sliderLine.frame.minX + offset
    }
    
    private func updateLineHeight() {
        let barSidePadding: CGFloat = 16.0
        let yMiddle: CGFloat = frame.height / 2.0
        let lineLeftSide: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: barSidePadding, y: yMiddle)
        let lineRightSide: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.width - barSidePadding,
                                             y: yMiddle)
        sliderLine.frame = CGRect(x: lineLeftSide.x,
                                  y: lineLeftSide.y,
                                  width: lineRightSide.x - lineLeftSide.x,
                                  height: lineHeight)
        sliderLine.cornerRadius = lineHeight / 2.0
        sliderLineBetweenHandles.cornerRadius = sliderLine.cornerRadius
    }
    
    private func updateColors() {
        let isInitial: Bool = selectedMinValue == minValue && selectedMaxValue == maxValue
        if let initialColor = initialColor?.cgColor, isInitial {
            minLabel.foregroundColor = initialColor
            maxLabel.foregroundColor = initialColor
            sliderLineBetweenHandles.backgroundColor = initialColor
            sliderLine.backgroundColor = initialColor
            
            let color: CGColor = (handleImage == nil) ? initialColor : UIColor.clear.cgColor
            rightHandle.backgroundColor = color
            rightHandle.borderColor = color
        } else {
            let tintCGColor: CGColor = tintColor.cgColor
            minLabel.foregroundColor = minLabelColor?.cgColor ?? tintCGColor
            maxLabel.foregroundColor = maxLabelColor?.cgColor ?? tintCGColor
            sliderLineBetweenHandles.backgroundColor = colorBetweenHandles?.cgColor ?? tintCGColor
            sliderLine.backgroundColor = tintCGColor
            
            let color: CGColor
            if let _ = handleImage {
                color = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            } else {
                color = handleColor?.cgColor ?? tintCGColor
            }
            rightHandle.backgroundColor = color
            rightHandle.borderColor = handleBorderColor.map { $0.cgColor }
        }
    }
    
    private func updateHandlePositions() {
        leftHandle.position = CGPoint(x: xPositionAlongLine(for: selectedMinValue),
                                      y: sliderLine.frame.midY)
        
        rightHandle.position = CGPoint(x: xPositionAlongLine(for: selectedMaxValue),
                                       y: sliderLine.frame.midY)
        
        sliderLineBetweenHandles.frame = CGRect(x: leftHandle.position.x,
                                                y: sliderLine.frame.minY,
                                                width: rightHandle.position.x -  leftHandle.position.x,
                                                height: lineHeight)
    }
    
    private func updateFixedLabelPositions() {
        minLabel.position = CGPoint(x: xPositionAlongLine(for: minValue),
                                    y: sliderLine.frame.minY - (minLabelTextSize.height / 2.0) - (handleDiameter / 2.0) - labelPadding)
        maxLabel.position = CGPoint(x: xPositionAlongLine(for: maxValue),
                                    y: sliderLine.frame.minY - (maxLabelTextSize.height / 2.0) - (handleDiameter / 2.0) - labelPadding)
        if minLabel.frame.minX < 0.0 {
            minLabel.frame.origin.x = 0.0
        }
        
        if maxLabel.frame.maxX > frame.width {
            maxLabel.frame.origin.x = frame.width - maxLabel.frame.width
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func refresh() {
        let diff: CGFloat = selectedMaxValue - selectedMinValue
        
        if diff < minDistance {
            switch handleTracking {
                case .left:
                    selectedMinValue = selectedMaxValue - minDistance
                case .right:
                    selectedMaxValue = selectedMinValue + minDistance
                case .none:
                    break
            }
        } else if diff > maxDistance {
            switch handleTracking {
                case .left:
                    selectedMinValue = selectedMaxValue - maxDistance
                case .right:
                    selectedMaxValue = selectedMinValue + maxDistance
                case .none:
                    break
            }
        }
        
        if selectedMinValue < minValue {
            selectedMinValue = minValue
        }
        if selectedMaxValue > maxValue {
            selectedMaxValue = maxValue
        }
        
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        updateHandlePositions()
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
    
    private func animate(handle: CALayer, selected: Bool) {
        let transform: CATransform3D
        if selected {
            transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(selectedHandleDiameterMultiplier, selectedHandleDiameterMultiplier, 1.0)
        } else {
            transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        }
        
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.3)
        CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut))
        handle.transform = transform
        
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}

private final class CustomUISliderLeftElement: UIAccessibilityElement {
    
    override func accessibilityIncrement() {
        guard let slider = accessibilityContainer as? CustomUISlider else { return }
        slider.selectedMinValue += slider.step
        accessibilityValue = slider.minLabel.string as? String
    }
    
    override func accessibilityDecrement() {
        guard let slider = accessibilityContainer as? CustomUISlider else { return }
        slider.selectedMinValue -= slider.step
        accessibilityValue = slider.minLabel.string as? String
    }
}

private final class CustomUISliderRightElement: UIAccessibilityElement {
    
    override func accessibilityIncrement() {
        guard let slider = accessibilityContainer as? CustomUISlider else { return }
        slider.selectedMaxValue += slider.step
        slider.refresh()
        accessibilityValue = slider.maxLabel.string as? String
    }
    
    override func accessibilityDecrement() {
        guard let slider = accessibilityContainer as? CustomUISlider else { return }
        slider.selectedMaxValue -= slider.step
        slider.refresh()
        accessibilityValue = slider.maxLabel.string as? String
    }
}

private extension CGRect {
    
    var center: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY)
    }
}

private extension CGPoint {
    
    func distance(to: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let distX: CGFloat = to.x - x
        let distY: CGFloat = to.y - y
        return sqrt(distX * distX + distY * distY)
    }
}
```

El código original lo puedes revisar en el siguiente link: [GitHub-RangeSeekSlider](https://github.com/WorldDownTown/RangeSeekSlider)

En el `ViewController` puedes setear la configuración del slider:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
       
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: CustomUISlider!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Configuras los valores del slider.
        slider.minValue = 0.0
        slider.maxValue = 100.0
        slider.selectedHandleDiameterMultiplier = 1.0
        slider.colorBetweenHandles = .red
        slider.lineHeight = 30.0
    }
}
```

El resultado final quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo probare y te aviso

Comment: Dale, y como dije en el otro post tocaría probar el anterior código con Xcode 12 que está por salir; otra cosa, el slider así de ancho está dentro de los rangos de Apple en la documentación de Human Interface Guidelines?

Comment: Es el ancho solicitado por el cliente,

Comment: No pude reescribir el codigo que me pasastes :(

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: Pues simplemente no pude traspasarlo estimado soy medio novato en iOS

Comment: Copia todo el código en un archivo limpio `.swift`. Luego a tu slider le agregas el nombre de la clase y listo. Si deseas puedes abrir un link de chat

Comment: Intenta ingresar https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221951/ios-uislider

Answer (score 0):

Espero que quieras editarlo en el guion gráfico, y solo el tamaño de la línea, úsalo en tu UISlider personalizado. Espero que te sea de utilidad.

```
class CustomSlide: UISlider {

   @IBInspectable var trackHeight: CGFloat = 2

   override func trackRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   //set your bounds here
      return CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSizeMake(bounds.width, trackHeight))
   }
}
```